# General solution to Differential equation ambiguity

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

With no other context than:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ay.$$

I understand the more popular solution that doesn’t involve imaginary numbers would simply be $y(x)=e^{ax}$.

But because of Euler’s identity, can I claim that $y(x)=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ is a general solution to the differential equation as well because $y’(x)=iy(x)$?

I am asking because if the differential equation is presented without claiming that $a\in\mathbb{R}$, can I just assume that $a$ is ‘allowed’ to take on imaginary values?

Comment: If people want to get a complex solution, then they should explicitly say this. Otherwise, I'd assume that the expected solution must be real.

Comment: It is hard to answer without some context. Certainly $x \mapsto c e^{ax}$ is the solution for any complex $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [This page](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20cos(x)%20%2B%20isin(x)) from WolframAlpha, I would agree that a solution to $$\frac{dy}{dx} = ay$$ is indeed $$y = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$ due to the fact that 
the alternate form of that equation turns out to be $$y = e^{ix}$$
Mind blown, eh?

Comment: Yes, Your mind is just as blown as Euler’s was I’m sure :)

Answer (score 0):

$y=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\quad$ is NOT general solution of $\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=ay.$

$y=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\quad$ is NOT particular solution of $\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=ay.$

If you put $\quad y=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\quad$ into $\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=ay \quad$ you get $\quad -\sin(x)+i\cos(x)=a(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))\quad$ which obviously is false, even with $a=1$.

Even with $a=1$, you see that your claim $y'(x)=i\:y(x)$ is false with $y(x)=\cos(x)+i\:\sin(x)$.

What is correct ?

The general solution of $\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=ay \quad$ is :
 $\quad y=c\:e^{ax}\quad$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

If you put $\quad y=c\:e^{ax}\quad$ into $\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=ay \quad$ you get $\quad c\:(a\:e^{ax})=a\:(c\:e^{ax})\quad$ which is correct.

Note that $\quad y=e^{ax}\quad$ is not the general solution. It is a particular solution which corresponds to the particular value of $c=1$.

Coming back to your question about the complex cases :

In the case where the parameter $a$ is complex, say $\quad a=r_1+i\:r_2\quad$ with $r_1$ and $r_2$ real, the general solution of $\quad \frac{dy}{dx}=(r_1+i\,r_2)y\quad$ is :
$$y=c\:e^{(r_1+i\,r_2)x}$$
$$y=c\:e^{r_1x}\:e^{i\,r_2x}$$
Because of Euler’s identity, it is the same as :
$$y=c\:e^{r_1x}\left(\cos(r_2x)+i\:\sin(r_2x)\right)$$

Comment: No. If $a=i$, the general solution is $y=c\left(\cos(x)+i\,\sin(x)\right)$ with $c$ an arbitrary coefficient. The solution that you propose $y=\cos(x)+i\,\sin(x)$ is not the general solution, it is a particular solution.

Comment: sorry I shouldn’t be using short hand by assuming the constant.  What I was trying to ask is if I assume $a$ takes the value of $i$, then $y=c[\cos(x)+i\,\sin(x)]$ is a general solution

Comment: This is consistent with my answer in the more general case $a=r_1+i\,r_2$. The case that you consider is $r1=0$ and $r_2=1$ which is included in my answer. I suppose that this finalizes the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution  for $$ y'=ay$$ is $$ y= C e^{ax} $$

If it happens that $$a=i$$

then$$ y=Ce^{ix}=C[ \cos(x) + i\ sin(x)] $$

In most real life problems $a$ is real number.